# Finding differences between Numpy arrays of different shapes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two Numpy arrays with different shapes, and need to find the differences

Array a has shape (114, 8).
Array b has shape (179, 8).

I know that every row in Array a is contained in Array b. I need a way to basically subtract Array a from Array b so I end up with:

Array c having shape (65, 8) that has NO duplicate entries between array a and array b.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EXAMPLE:

```
a = array([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
b = array([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])
```

I want to be able to remove all elements of array a from array b so I can end up with:

```
c = array([7,8,9])
```

Comment: Can you please show a small, but representative example?

Comment: just added an example! thanks!

Comment: A brute-force approach would be to take a slice of B that has the same size as A and comparing it with A. If it is not equal, repeat with a different slice shifted by one position. Once equal, you know the position where A occurs in B and can add the parts before and after to the result C. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of many ways you could do this:

```
#example data

import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

c = []
for row in b:
    if row in a:
        pass
    else:
        c.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is efficient and sophisticated enough but hope this helps.

```
c = [np.array(x) for x in b if x not in a]  
c = np.array(c).reshape(-1,8)
```